# One custom toolbar for multiple layouts in FileMaker Pro

Tags: header, toolbar, filemaker

I have a complex Filemaker database with multiple tables and layouts. What I would like to do is to add a toolbar to each layout. This, of course in view of maintainability of my database solution.

Of course, I could create a nice row of buttons (for example in the header of the layout) and copy past this to each separate layout. However, this is not really a great solution from a maintenance pont of view (if you want to change something you need to do so multiple times).

So... is there another way?

I am looking for something similar to e.g., include in php:

```
<?php 
    include 'header.php';
?>
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It could be achieved, mostly, with a bit of extra work. There is nothing out of the box, although you might find some samples on the web.

The closest thing in FileMaker is button bar with styles. Even this will not auto-update by default across different layouts.

You can use a webviewer based on a global field.

Another solution for older versionsis to use a portal with records creating buttons and a script which will do staff depending in which row button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you. I guess using a button bar will already help a great deal. Still a bit unsatisfactory though that there is no built in solution.

Comment: I agree on the button bar being the best option. For those unfamiliar with them, there's an example navigation scheme [here](https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/filemaker-navigation-bar) on the Soliant blog. Beezwax also put out a [good post](https://blog.beezwax.net/2015/05/12/fmp14-button-bars/) with some clear button bar examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Navigation Window which may be recalled by either a push button which should be on each layout (you have not to change it because it only recall the Navigation Window) and/or a Script (I use to put it at the first place, as CMD-1).

Of course, you need to manage that the Navigation Window has to be closed before the navigation and execution of the Script managed by your Toolbar while, at the other side, you may add every other navigation need ;-)

Best wishes

Carmine Iaciofano - Area

Comment: Do you mean that the user needs to push a button to get the menu? I guess that would be acceptable for a mobile application, where menu's are often hidden. However, this is a desktop-oriented solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I use it for desktop solution and it is appreciated both as push button and Script. It's more a mobile solution, you are right, but we have to consider that the GUI are going to converge and what is good for Mobile may also be good for Desktop. Anyway, it's up to you and it's also good to know if someone has a better solution. I will appreciate it, too.